# Replace using Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have
2,5-3,5
3,5-4,5
...
and want
2.5-3.5
3.5-4.5

My "Find what" in Replace look like
[0-9],[0-9]

But I cannot make "Replace with"
\2.\1 to work. Nor does $2.$1.

This is clearly a simple task. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Unless you wanted to reverse the digits, you want the replacement to be \1.\2, not \2.\1.  You probably knew that.

Comment: Is there like somebody out there who detests Notepad++ so much, he must silently vote to move every other Notepad++ question to Super User? It's almost always this one guy...

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify groups to use replacement tags.  I don't use notepad+, but if it's similar to other regex implementations `\([0-9]\),\([0-9]\)` should do the trick.

Comment: If it is similar to other regex implementations (which it is, **somewhat**), those backslashes aren't supposed to be there.

Comment: @BoltClock: it depends on the default level of 'magic'.  In VIM, for example, the slashes have to be there in the default magic setting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked Regular Expression checkbox(Search mode) in Notepad search and replace dialog?

I have just tried, this will work just fine for your case.

```
Search string: (\d),(\d)

Replace string: \1.\2
```

If you want to be more precise you can search and replace like this

```
Search string: (\d),(\d)-(\d),(\d)

Replace string: \1.\2-\3.\4
```

End just for reminder here is picture where you have to check regular expression option

[image]